# “Laravel Livewire” Actively updating quantity of a product inside a loop results in input values synchronizing with each other

Tags: php, laravel, input, foreach, laravel-livewire

I hope someone can help me with this since I'm new to programming. I've been building an auto parts search engine displaying selected parts from a loop, in the back end seems to work like a charm, whenever i submit any new quantity it immediately updates the DB of that item BUT "all the inputs are synced together and if I change the value inside an input box, all of the others change too, but it only updates the one I selected(as intended).

I tried removing one of the actions leaving only the `wire:click`, but I don't know how to send the input value to the function, and if a leave the `wire:model` I don't know how to make it trigger a function, Thank you for your answer.

My view:

```
@foreach($carparts as $carpart)
    <input type="number"
           id="qty"
           name="qty"
           value="{{$carpart->qty}}"
           wire:click="updateqty({{$carpart->id}})"
           wire:model="newQty">
    <p>{{$carpart->name}}</p>
@endforeach
```

My controller:

```
public $newQty;

public function updateqty($id)
{
    $partqty = Mypart::findOrFail($id);
    $partqty->qty = $this->newQty;
    $partqty->save();
}

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.selectparts', [
        'carparts' => Mypart::where('mycar_id', $this->mycar)->get()
    ]);
}
```

mycar is the selected car

Comment: The problem might be that you have multiple inputs with the same id, maybe try something like `id="qty-{{$carpart->id}}"`, that way you should always have a unique id for each input.

Comment: I've never seen that one before, thank you very much i will try that